# Phonegap - confused about Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using PhoneGap and Framework7 (UI) for my app. The app will be deployed on IOS, Android and Windows.

The app needs to play audio and also record audio. I will be using alot of javascript code for checking user answers and adding user scores.

My problem.
I looked at a few tutorials and examples. I am really confused.
I am using the latest version of PhoneGap. I am using PhoneGap Desktop to create a new project. I also downloaded the PhoneGap app to run it on my device. (All working)

My confusion.
I see in some tutorials it says this.

> In order to create a PhoneGap project for Android, all you have to do
>   is run the command to add a platform to the project: $ phonegap platform add android

Do I need to add this too? I have created a build for the android version using PhoneGap Build ([www.build.phonegap.com](http://www.build.phonegap.com))

Do I have to change my app structure to accommidate both IOS and Android?

Is there a way to build for IOS on PhoneGap build without a certificate/key from Apple? I just want to test the app and see if its working on IOS. I am still in the beginning stage of development.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The PhoneGap Desktop / Developer app combination, while great, is not a perfect representation of how your app will behave when built and installed on its own. You will need to do further testing to ensure your app works as expected.

   - The templates usually come with all the core plugins installed. These will ask for far more permissions than your app actually needs. You'll need to remove these from `config.xml` at some point prior to production.
2. `config.xml` is the preferred mechanism now for indicating which platforms and plugins are required by your app. Any missing platform or plugin will be automatically installed by any of the build tools (CLI or PhoneGap Build). See the [Cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html) and [PhoneGap Build](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/) documentation for more information.

   - PhoneGap Build determines which platforms you want to build for by looking for `<platform name="...">` tags in your `config.xml` file. If you have none, all platforms are built, but at some point you'll need to limit this to the platforms you intend to target.
   - Note: **IF** you have the CLI installed, you can add platforms and save them in your config.xml by using `cordova platform add --save android`.
   - The same applies to plugins. Note that the PhoneGap Developer app only supports core plugins and a few third-party plugins.
3. You do not usually need to change your project structure to support iOS and Android. You *may* need to handle quirks that are present on each OS, but you should be able to do so using the same code base.
4. You cannot build an app on PhoneGap Build for iOS without having the requisite certificate and provisioning profile from Apple.

Comment: Thanks Kerri, this helped me